# LDAP search for attributes in the hierarchy of an object

Tags: ldap, hierarchy

I am looking for a query allowing to extract information from an object, but also for information from the hierarchy of this object.
For example,

1) user name DN is
    `DN:cn=user.name@location,ou=Org1,ou=Org2,o=Org`

Attributes of `cn=user.name@location` are
    `cn=user@location`
    `sn=name`
    `givenname=user name`
    `mail=user.name@thecompany.com`

2) Org1 DN is
    `DN: ou=Org1,ou=Org2,o=Org`

Attributes for Org1 are
    `ou=Org1`
    `AreaCode=London`
    `DistCode=125`

3) Org2 DN is
    `DN:ou=Org2,o=Org`

Attributes for Org2 are
    `ou=Org2`
    `CountryCode=GB`
    `DealCode=2`

When I set the filter on `cn=user.name@location`, how can I get attribute value of `DistCode` from `ou=Org1` and value of `DealCode` from `ou=Org2` with one (or multiple) query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the values of "ou" and "cn" attributes are unique on the different levels of the hierarchy (e.g. "cn=user.name@location,ou=Org1,ou=Org2,o=Org" does not contain "ou" attribute!), you could perform a sub-tree search on the base "ou=Org2,o=org" (or even "o=org") with a filter "(|(ou=Org2)(ou=Org1)(cn=user@location)) and would get 3 objects back.

Comment: It worlks partially. Indeed, the query provide the information, but it is not provided in one result, I mean it provides the result for OU and the information for the CN separately. But the purpose of the query is providing the OU result AND the CN result in one data set.